# Bokeh – ColumnDataSource not updating whiskered-plot

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, bokeh

I’m having issues with the following code (I’ve cut out large pieces but I can add them back in – these seemed like the important parts).  In my main code, I set up a plot (“sectionizePlot”) which is a simple variation on another whiskered-plot

I’m looking to update them on the fly.  In the same script, I’m using a heatmap (“ModifiedGenericHeatMap”) which updates fine.
Any ideas how I might update my whiskered-plot?  Updating the ColumnDataSource doesn’t seem to work (which makes sense).  I’m guessing that I am running into issues with adding each circle/point individually onto the plot.
One idea would be to clear the plot each time and manually add the points onto the plot, but it would need to be cleared each time, which I’m unsure of how to do.
Any help would be appreciated.  I’m just a lowly Scientist trying to utilize Bokeh in Pharma research.

```
def ModifiedgenericHeatMap(source, maxPct):
    colors = ["#75968f", "#a5bab7", "#c9d9d3", "#e2e2e2", "#dfccce", "#ddb7b1", "#cc7878", "#933b41", "#550b1d"]
    #mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette=colors, low=0, high=data['count'].max())
    mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette=colors, low=0, high=maxPct)
    TOOLS = "hover,save,pan,box_zoom,reset,wheel_zoom"
    globalDist = figure(title="derp",
                        x_range=cols, y_range=list(reversed(rows)),
                        x_axis_location="above", plot_width=1000, plot_height=400,
                        tools=TOOLS, toolbar_location='below')
    globalDist.grid.grid_line_color = None
    globalDist.axis.axis_line_color = None
    globalDist.axis.major_tick_line_color = None
    globalDist.axis.major_label_text_font_size = "5pt"
    globalDist.axis.major_label_standoff = 0
    globalDist.xaxis.major_label_orientation = pi / 3
    globalDist.rect(x="cols", y="rows", width=1, height=1,
                    source=source,
                    fill_color={'field': 'count', 'transform': mapper},
                    line_color=None)
    color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=mapper, major_label_text_font_size="5pt",
                         ticker=BasicTicker(desired_num_ticks=len(colors)),
                         # fix this via using a formatter with accounts for
                         formatter=PrintfTickFormatter(format="%d%%"),
                         label_standoff=6, border_line_color=None, location=(0, 0))
    text_props = {"source": source, "text_align": "left", "text_baseline": "middle"}
    x = dodge("cols", -0.4, range=globalDist.x_range)
    r = globalDist.text(x=x, y=dodge("rows", 0.3, range=globalDist.y_range), text="count", **text_props)
    r.glyph.text_font_size = "8pt"
    globalDist.add_layout(color_bar, 'right')
    globalDist.select_one(HoverTool).tooltips = [
        ('Well:', '@rows @cols'),
        ('Count:', '@count'),
    ]
    return globalDist

def sectionizePlot(source, source_error, type, base):
    print("sectionize plot created with typ: " + type)
    colors = []
    for x in range(0, len(base)):
        colors.append(getRandomColor())
    title = type + "-wise Intensity Distribution"
    p = figure(plot_width=600, plot_height=300, title=title)
    p.add_layout(
        Whisker(source=source_error, base="base", upper="upper", lower="lower"))
    for i, sec in enumerate(source.data['base']):
        p.circle(x=source_error.data["base"][i], y=sec, color=colors[i])
    p.xaxis.axis_label = type
    p.yaxis.axis_label = "Intensity"
    if (type.split()[-1] == "Row"):
        print("hit a row")
        conv = dict(enumerate(list("nABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP")))
        conv.pop(0)
        p.xaxis.major_label_overrides = conv
    p.xaxis.ticker = SingleIntervalTicker(interval=1)
    return p

famData = dict()
e1FractSource = ColumnDataSource(dict(count=[], cols=[], rows=[], index=[]))
e1Fract = ModifiedgenericHeatMap(e1FractSource, 100)
rowSectTotSource = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(base=[]))
rowSectTotSource_error = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(base=[], lower=[], upper=[]))
rowSectPlot_tot = sectionizePlot(rowSectTotSource,rowSectTotSource_error, "eSum Row", rowBase)

def update(selected=None):
    global famData
    famData = getFAMData(file_source_dt1, True)
    global e1Stack
    e1Fract = (famData['e1Sub'] / famData['eSum']) * 100
    e1Stack = e1Fract.stack(dropna=False).reset_index()
    e1Stack.columns = ["rows", "cols", "count"]
    e1Stack['count'] = e1Stack['count'].apply(lambda x: round(x, 1))
    e1FractSource.data = dict(cols=e1Stack["cols"], count=(e1Stack["count"]),
                              rows=e1Stack["rows"], index=e1Stack.index.values, codon=wells, )

    rowData, colData = sectionize(famData['eSum'], rows, cols)
    rowData_lower, rowData_upper = getLowerUpper(rowData)
    rowBase = list(range(1, 17))
    rowSectTotSource_error.data = dict(base=rowBase, lower=rowData_lower, upper=rowData_upper, )
    rowSectTotSource.data = dict(base=rowData)
    rowSectPlot_tot.title.text = "plot changed in update"

layout = column(e1FractSource, rowSectPlot_tot)
update()

curdoc().add_root(layout)
curdoc().title = "Specs"
print("ok")
```

Comment: It's not completely clear where the updates are coming from for your plots. It looks like you've used [sliders.py](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/sliders.py) as a base for your app/server. I would recommend stripping the plot down there most basic requirements, getting the update to work, then building them up again.